# Confidence interval based anomaly detection

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, confidence-interval

My question is related to confidence intervals and outlier detection. Here is the scenario, imagine that my distribution is fully normal distributed with 0 means, 1 scale. Then I can represent this distribution in python using scipy like;

```
from scipy.stats import norm

mean = 0
var = 1
dist = norm(mean, var)
```

Then, for example, I have also been able to compute confidence intervals for 95% like this;

```
dist.interval(0.95)
```

where the result is (-1.959963984540054, 1.959963984540054)

These points represent the critical points for my distribution with a specific (95%) confidence interval. According to that information, I can calculate the area under the curve for these critical points like this;

```
dist.cdf(-1.959963984540054), dist.cdf(1.959963984540054)
```

where CDF represents the cumulative distribution function in scipy and the result for those points is 0.025, 0.975.

And here is my question; when I want to test a random point -eg 7.25- whether fit my previous distribution or not, I can calculate the z-score - (7.25 - mean) / var -.

Then I can interpret that if the calculated z-score is bigger than for example 3.0, I can say that my point (7.25) doesn't fit the given distribution. (3.0 is a complete hyperparameter, I'm absolutely aware of this situation)

Do I have a chance to calculate CDF for this point (7.25) which equals 0.9999999999999899, then compare this ~0.9999 point with previously calculated area pieces of information which are 0.025 and 0.975 to say that because my CDF(7.25) equals ~0.9999 is not resides in 0.025 and 0.975 regions, my 7.25 point can be identified as an outlier?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Various issue here.  "(7.25 - mean) / var" will give you the wrong answer.;  at a minimum you should be dividing by the standard deviation (the square root of the variance) rather than the variance.  If you reject data which is more than $1.96$ standard deviations from the mean then you will reject $5\%$ of the data you should have included if you have a normal distribution and possibly more for other distributions, which may not be a good idea. Confidence intervals are typically used to indicate uncertainty of estimators, for example of the mean, not of the distribution itself.

Comment: @Henry, thanks for your correction about the variance-std.

Comment: @Henry what about this question. Actually i'm trying to answer this question 'can i check any random value, which has not included in the stage of the estimating the distribution parameters, using confidence interval?' It means that after estimation of distribution parameters can i say that any random value for example 7.25 in here is not fit to this distribution in 95% conf.

Comment: If you generate $1000$ values from a normal distribution then about $50$ will not fit in this interval, but they will have come from that distribution.